# PHP gets empty data from AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I would like to create a simple "Deselect All" functionality on a filter-based selection. I read on the Internet that AJAX would be a perfect tool for it so I dove in to code, but I can't seem to get any data from the AJAX data field.

Just to clarify, I am totally new to AJAX and somewhat proficient with `PHP`.

This is my script function that is triggered by clicking on a clickable HTML element. What I am trying to do is pass the data to PHP so that it knows which filter field to deselect and clear.

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sport").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: {filter: "sport"},
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data){
                alert("Success: " + data);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This above snippet works on click as I am getting the alert window in browser.

This below is my PHP test file with which I am trying to get the data posted by my AJAX function:

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
    $filter = $_GET['filter'];
    echo $filter;
?>
```

I have tried multiple dataTypes in the AJAX function, but I either kept getting "null" from json or empty string from "text". Then when I tried creating a random array within ajax.php, that worked fine using `json_encode()`.

This only alerts "Success: " instead of "Success: sport" as I would expect. Can anybody help me understand please?

Comment: in your AJAX your chosen method is ```method: "POST"``` but in your php your have written ```$_GET['filter'];``` ... it should be ```$_POST['filter'];```  seems like a typing error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use method `POST` as you specified in the call.

```
<?php
    $filter = $_POST['filter'];
    echo $filter;
?>
```

Comment: I literally just figured that out like 15 minutes ago. The way I saw the answers on the internet was that they needed to be the opposite such as AJAX was posting the data and PHP was getting it. Thank you!